# Protocol 'View' requirement '_makeView(view:inputs:). swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob-rewardedvideoad

what should I change?
I am trying to make rewarded ad in swiftui

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewardedAdView` should be a `struct`, not a `class`. If you need an `NSObject` subclass to use as a delegate or for the target/action pattern, make it the `Coordinator` type of `RewardedAdView`.

Watch [Integrating SwiftUI from WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/) for an explanation of how to implement a `Coordinator` class.